# Add the same value to multiple vectors in Matlab

Tags: matlab, variables, vector, addition

I have a Matlab script that looks like this:

```
onsets=cell(1,5);
onsets{1}=[353.1    389.9   404 431.3];
onsets{2}=[369.8    385.8   427.7];
onsets{3}=[344.6    359.7   397.5];
onsets{4}=[364.7    415.1   420.1];
onsets{5}=[146  174.6   204.2];
```

I want to add 2.24 to all vectors (now I am doing it vector by vector) and to get the output that would look like this:

```
onsets=cell(1,5);
onsets{1}=[355.3400  392.1400  406.2400  433.5400];
onsets{2}=[372.0400  388.0400  429.9400];
onsets{3}=[346.8400  361.9400  399.7400];
onsets{4}=[346.8400  361.9400  399.7400];
onsets{5}=[366.9400  417.3400  422.3400];
```

What is the faster and more efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`cellfun`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) to apply an operation to all cell contents:

```
result = cellfun(@(x) x+2.24, onsets, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Comment: I guess this is the most natural one-line solution, but note that under the hood this will not be much different from looping over the cell array and adding the 2.24 in each step of the loop. -- I would say, just use which you find most readable.